# Android how to set app:tabBackground attribute programatically?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout connected to viewpager and tablayout is shown using a selector drawable to show bubbles/Dots as page section indicator.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_type_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/progress_assignment_tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />
```

progress_assignment_tab_selector is a selector drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_content_selected_dot"
    android:state_selected="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_default_dot"/>
```

I would like to change the `app:tabBackground` dynamically at run time. I do not find a way to set the selector drwable dynamically to the tab.

Any help is appreciated.!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
tabLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable));
```

Try this to change the 1st position -

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(R.drawable.your_layout);
```

Comment: This sets background for entire tablayout. What I need is to set background for each tab alone with a layer list of drawables for page selected and unselected state.

Comment: I would have been OK with setting all tabs in one go, but this doesn't work for tab layout statelist drawables.